# Compute Date out of Timestamp from Binance-API (Python)

Tags: python, api, date, timestamp

I received the servertime from the Binance-API,I try to work with and it looks like this:

```
{
  "serverTime": 1518440400000
}
```

The question is, how can I compute the date out of this stamp?

I tried

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
       int("1518308894652")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

But the date wasn´t valid.

Do you have ideas, or is it to specific?
Thank you!

Comment: Is `1518440400000` is the actual timestamp you got back? If so, that would mean the server is running in the year 50087... But assuming that's just an example, most languages should have some function for this. What language are you using?

Comment: this is the same, what I got.  I use python.

Comment: Question would have been so much more useful if you had posted the Binance API request.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1518308894652"))
```

But python says the year is out of range (understandably, considering it says it's 50087). So I suspect that `serverTime` is not a normal timestamp.

But assuming the response that you got was the timestamp, so you don't need to do any other conversions other than turning the string into an int.

## Edit:

Turns out the docs say "All time and timestamp related fields are in milliseconds." So just divide the response by 1000 and you'll be fine: `datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1518308894652")/1000)`. [Source](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#general-api-information)

Comment: I tried, but receive "ValueError: year 50083 is out of range"  :/

Comment: @cosmonaut I edited the question with the fix. The Binance API docs gives the time is in milliseconds, whereas python expects a value in seconds.

Comment: @AidanGawronski I don't know if you're referring to the fact that accepted answer was switched, or my answer itself. I'm super sorry that that it was switched, I didn't mean for that to happen. I wrote a short answer while I researched the problem further, planning to edit my answer to give more info on the problem, and in that time you posted your answer. But I found all of this completely independently, I just googled "Binance API".

Comment: Fair enough. I believe you.

Answer (score 18):

Your response is in [milliseconds](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) when datetime.fromtimestamp requires seconds.

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1518308894652/1000))

# 2018-02-10 19:28:14.652000
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas can handle this perfectly by specifying miliseconds as the unit.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(1518440400000, unit='ms')
```

## Timestamp('2018-02-12 13:00:00')