# how to convert open time into real time?

Tags: python-3.x, database, time, pycharm, binance

[
[
1499040000000,      // Open time
"0.01634790",       // Open
"0.80000000",       // High
"0.01575800",       // Low
"0.01577100",       // Close
"148976.11427815",  // Volume
1499644799999,      // Close time
"2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
308,                // Number of trades
"1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
"28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
"17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
]
]

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757836/compute-date-out-of-timestamp-from-binance-api-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute Date out of Timestamp from Binance-API (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757836/compute-date-out-of-timestamp-from-binance-api-python)